# Simple parse of an int into a string

Tags: c#, string, parsing, int

In my class, my teacher showed me something similar to this. Visual Studio is saying string doesn't have a definition for parse. I remember in class the teacher said it was `something.parse(thingyouwanttoparse)`. No commas. I've searched online, but all the options are different to the one the teacher showed me. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (!ValidMenuOption)
{
    string errorMsg = "\n\t Option must be ";
    int iteration = 1;
    while (iteration <=numAvailable)
    {
        errorMsg = errorMsg + string.parse(iteration) + ", ";
        iteration += 1
    }
    errorMsg = errorMsg + "or 0";
    Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
} //end if
```

Comment: It is highly recommended to state the programming language you're using (and tag it too)

Comment: perhaps you are trying for string.Format(thingyouwanttoformat)?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Convert int to string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3081916/299327)

Comment: Parse is generally used for making a string into a number, date, collection of smaller strings etc. Format is generally used for making something into a string. This applies both to words in sentences and to the functions you call. In your case all you seem to need is `iteration.ToString()`

Answer (score 3):

Parsing is when you turn a string into a thing. Formatting is the opposite of parsing, and in C# you can format an int by calling `.ToString()` on it. If you're concatenating strings, then you can even leave this method call off, so your code probably becomes

```
if (!ValidMenuOption){
    string errorMsg = "\n\t Option must be ";
    int iteration = 1;
    while (iteration <=numAvailable) {                        
        errorMsg = errorMsg + iteration + ", ";
        iteration+=1;
    }
    errorMsg = errorMsg + "or 0"; 
    Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you could have done it this way too:

```
if (!ValidMenuOption){
    string errorMsg = "\n\t Option must be "+string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1, numAvailable)) + " or 0"; 
    Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
}
```