# Passing variables as parameters from textbox to C# responsetext

Tags: c#

Consider:

```
int x = 10;
```

and `String str = "x";`.

I want to output 10 by calling the `str` variable as it has value `x`. But the problem is it is a `string x` with `""` to be called in:

```
response.write();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: unable to understand !,rephrase ur statements

Comment: Depending on how and where you declare `x`, maybe you can use reflection. But maybe just using a `Dictionary<string, int>` will suffice for what you're trying to do.

Comment: A string is a string.  A variable is a variable.  You do not cast a variable to a String by surrounding it in quotes.  Try String str = x.ToString();  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081916/convert-int-to-string-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a container.. something like this:

```
class Container {
    public int X { get; set; }

    public Container() {
        X = 10;
    }
}

// .. elsewhere...

object getVariableValueByStringName(string str) {
    return typeof(Container).GetProperty(str).GetValue(new Container() /* <-- dummy or not.. up to you -->);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to output the value of x i.e. 10 in response.write(). You can even do that without the String variable `str`, like:

```
response.write(x);

or response.write(x.ToString());
```

And as per your code

```
int x = 10;
and

String str = x.ToString();
```

instead of String str = "x".