# Int custom ToString

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, int

I would like to print out UInt32 as ##,##,##.
Comma every two digits.
Is there a way to do this?

```
ToString("N0");
```

Is a comma every three digits

Comment: You can do something like Regex.Replace(myUnit32.ToString(), ".{2}", "$0,")

Comment: @Hakunamatata i got something like `12,34,` as output.

Comment: @active92 You can remove last comma if you change regex to .{2}(?!$)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081916/convert-int-to-string
http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-an-int-to-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use (with `using System.Globalization;`):

```
yourUInt.ToString("N0", new NumberFormatInfo { NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 2, }, })
```

Documentation: [`NumberGroupSizes` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes.aspx)

---

Of course, this `NumberGroupSizes` property can also be set on the `NumberFormat` property of a `CultureInfo` (possibly obtained by cloning an existing read-only `CultureInfo`) which can then be assigned to `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.