# How do I apply the Settings.settings values at design time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, application-settings, design-time

I have a panel in my Form like this:

[image]

and a Panel_BackColor in project's **Settings.setting** file:

[image]

I can change panel back color in the Form constructor:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel1.BackColor = UI_Settings.Default.Panel_BackColor;
        }
    }
```

All things work at runtime:

[image]

But nothing change at Design Time. How can I apply these settings at Design mode too?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked ["not edited version"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55599477/revisions) of this question on [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d6960df-1866-4837-8e7c-a4879c2f535e/how-do-i-apply-the-settingssettings-values-at-design-time?forum=csharpgeneral#8d6960df-1866-4837-8e7c-a4879c2f535e) and got an answer within an hour.

Questions like [Convert int to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3081916/579381) is a good questions but mine is not! 
I think stackoverflow should keep a watch on it's editors and policy.

**The answer:**

Select your control in Form Designer (for example a button), go to Properties, `(ApplicationSettings)`,`(PropertyBinding)`, then bind `BackColor` or other property to `Button_BackColor` or other settings. Afterward by changing settings in **Settings.settings** file, all binded controls would be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I got your question, I try to handle with it when I use MetroFramework. Some changes just shown in runtime because it use another ***drawing technic*** with xml or .netframework when you use runtime code. So, I think you can't see changes in design time.

Answer (score -1):

Next time try to explain a little more in details or maybe add some code or images to make us understand better.

In C# you have the property:

```
//Namespace: System.ComponentModel

//Gets a value that indicates whether the Component is currently in design mode.
//true if the Component is in design mode; otherwise, false.
protected bool DesignMode { get; }
```