# Convert an integer to character

Tags: c#

How do I convert the result of:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var x = rnd.Next(1,4);
```

if x is 1 I just need it to be '1', if it is 2 I just need it to be '2', and if it is 3 I just need it to be '3'. Basically just add the quotation marks. Thank you.

Comment: you could `type cast` like `(string)rnd.Next(1,4);` or do a `rnd.Next(1,4).toString();`

Comment: @PrashanthBenny that `(string)rnd.Next` would not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert int to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081916/convert-int-to-string)

Comment: @Hans Passant I need '1' not "1" Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, here are a couple of them:

Add the char zero (only works if it's one digit):

```
var c = (char)('0' + rnd.Next(1,4));
```

Convert to string and get the first character:

```
var c = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString().ToCharArray()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to string :

```cs
var x = rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()[0]
```

Comment: Why `ToCharArray()`, when `string` has indexer?

Comment: You can directly access a string character: `rnd.Next(1, 4).ToString()[0];`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this number to the char `'0'` to get the char value.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var x = rnd.Next(1,4);
char c = Convert.ToChar(x + '0');
Console.WriteLine("x : " + x + " - c : " + c); // Outputs : x : 1 - c : 1
```

Comment: This is my favourite

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a string literal including the single quotes instead of creating an actual char as described in other answers, do this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var x = rnd.Next(1,4).ToString(@"\'#\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert:

```
(int)1 to '1'
(int)2 to '2'
(int)3 to '3'
...
```

which is basically a function

```
char NumberToChar(int n) => (char)('0' + n);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option, because we don't have enough yet:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var x = rnd.Next(1,4);
char c;
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        c = '1';
        break;
    case 2:
        c = '2';
        break;
    case 3:
        c = '3';
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now my answer is perfect.