# System.InvalidCastException with iennumrable cast

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

why I see `System.InvalidCastException` for the below code?

```cs
object[] obj = new object[5];
obj[0] = 1;
obj[0] = 2;
obj[0] = 3;
obj[0] = 4;
obj[0] = 5;
var exc = obj.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Unable to cast object of type `System.Int32` to type `System. String`.

Comment: This is because you cannot directly cast an `int` to a `string`. Instead look at the [many ways to convert it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081916/convert-int-to-string)

Comment: Because you are trying to cast `int` to `string`, but they are different types

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert int to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081916/convert-int-to-string)

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You make the assumption that `int` can be directly cast to `string` (in cannot)
2. You assume that if `#1` was valid, that `Cast<T>` would then perform that cast (it won't)

To get passed the first problem, you can simply project the source using `Select` and call `ToString` in the selector function (I make the assumption below that you didn't intend to assign *all five values to index `0`* but actually meant to populate the array in full):

```
var obj = new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = obj.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Alternatively you could use `Convert.ToString`:

```
var obj = new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = obj.Select(c => Convert.ToString(c)).ToList();
```

Both of these remove the "need" for `Cast<>` and solve problem `#2` in the process.

It's important to note that even if there was an `implicit` or `explicit` conversion from `int` to `string`, that `Cast<int>` would **not** perform the cast. This is because the function relies on a *generic cast* which does not invoke conversion operators. The source objects must be the same type as the generic argument. `Cast` is used for non-generic `IEnumerable` collections that existed pre-Linq allowing you to convert to an `IEnumerable<T>` to enable using LINQ operations. For example (broken into parts):

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
DataRowCollection drc = dt.Rows;
IEnumerable<DataRow> idr = drc.Cast<DataRow>();
var result = idr.Select(dr => GetDataFromDataRow(dr)).ToList();
```