# Not sure what it wrong here and how to fix it

Tags: c#

How do I convert the integer for hp as its giving me this error message:
`cannot convert from 'int' to 'string' [PokemonPocket]`

```
   if (menu == '1') {
      // We, probably, want to add just once
      Console.Write("Enter Pokemon Name:");
      string name = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.Write("Enter Pokemon HP: ");
      int hp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

      Console.Write("Enter Pokemon EXP: ");
      int exp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      if (myDictionary.Count <= 0) { 
        myDictionary.Add("Pokemon Name: ", name);
        myDictionary.Add("Pokemon HP: ", hp);
```

Comment: Have you tried googling exactly what you just said? It sounds like a question that should already have been asked and answered. E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081916/convert-int-to-string). If that does not answer your question, you can edit it to clarify what is different and it will be added into the reopen review queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myDictionary` appears to be a `Dictionary<string, string>` type. Seeing as you store `"Pokemon Name:"` and `"name"` just fine one line above.

As such, you can just call `hp.ToString()` to store it. Make sure to once again convert it back to int when using it though.

Alternatively, you can make a `Dictionary<string, object>` storage to keep track of your information and simply cast the values when you retrieve them:

```cs
string name = (string)myDictionary["Pokemon Name:"];
int hp = (int)myDictionary["Pokemon HP:"];
```