# CS0029: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

1. Summarize the problem

Adding an object to a list after reading its properties from a SQL Server `SELECT` statement - I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Include details about your goal

- My goal is to read asset changes from the database by using a `SELECT` T-SQL statement, reading and appending them into a list and display them using the list in a view.

Describe expected and actual results

- Expected: No error pops up.
- Actual: The error mentioned earlier pops up.

Include any error messages

- Already mentioned earlier.

2. Describe what you’ve tried

Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081940/13510906
- Getting the value as an integer, then converting it to a string.

```
//UserID = reader.GetString(0),
//AssetID = reader.GetString(1),
UserID = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString(),
AssetID = reader.GetInt32(1).ToString(),
```

- Making sure both variables `UserID` and `AssetID` use `int`

The same error still pops up.

3. Show some code

When appropriate, share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem (also called a minimum, reproducible example)

I don't know how to produce a minimum example without breaking the project in one way or another.

There's the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jKwuPA8ebJE-i-l3bkZ8B5iMrT_vq1sm/view?usp=sharing) to download the project. After downloading it, extract and run it.

The email address and password are `john@gmail.com` and `john123` respectively. You should see "Asset History" on the top navigation bar. Click on it to produce the problem.

Comment: Also can you please post all relevant code?

Comment: Hello @GuruStron, please check the post again.

Comment: What is the type of column `0` and `1`, and what are the types of the variables you are trying to set?

Comment: @Charlieface
Type of column:          Type of variable:
`0`:  Integer                         Integer
`1`:  Integer                         Integer

Comment: Then you want `GetInt32`, or you can use a cast `(int)reader[0]`

Comment: It turns out I've been grabbing the wrong columns from the database all along. There goes an error, here comes another one.

Answer (score 0):

Since both your variables/properties are integers you shouldn't convert them to strings:

```
UserID = reader.GetInt32(0),
AssetID = reader.GetInt32(1),
```

If you later need to add them to list of strings the you can call `ToString` there (`UserID.ToString(), AssetID.ToString()`)

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work. ToString() doesn't either. 
I'll try to see which property/properties is/are in `int` before adding them to the SQL table to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetString` Method (Int32) needs an integer (column index) as a parameter.Additionally you can add ToString() after transactions.

```cs
UserID = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Column Name")),
AssetID = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Column Name")),
```

Comment: Complier: Now I can't convert string to int.

Answer (score -2):

you can't implicitly assign string to integer, you need to parse the string, in this case using `int.Parse`

your code could me something like this:

```
UserID = int.Parse( reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
AssetID = int.Parse(reader.GetInt32(1).ToString());
```

for more information about follow this [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/convert-string-to-int).

Comment: `GetInt32` already returns `int` so you are basically converting int to string and then back to int, which is pointless